# How do I solve this integrating factor for this first order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the solution for $(t-1) \frac{dx}{dt} - x - t =0$

My attempt:

Dividing throughout $(t-1)$

$\frac{dx}{dt} - \frac{1}{t-1} x = \frac{t}{t-1}$

Integrating factor: $I(t) = e^{\int -\frac{1}{t-1} dt} = e^{- \ln t-1} = - \ln (t-1)$

However, I've been told that the correct integrating factor is $\frac{1}{t-1}$, How are they equal or where have I went wrong?

Comment: $$- \ln(t-1) \ne e^{-\ln(t-1)} = e^{\ln ((t-1)^{-1})} = (t-1)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general,

$$e^{\ln(x)} = x$$

This is how the logarithm is defined: as the inverse to exponentiation. Hence, using a logarithm property (that $\ln(1/x) = - \ln(x)$), you should have

$$e^{-\ln(t-1)} = e^{\ln \left( \frac{1}{t-1} \right)} = \frac{1}{t-1}$$